# Why does Google App Engine NDB return StringProperty(...) for a property value when inside of a @classmethod in the ndb.Model?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a simple NDB model:

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
import logging
from libs import Api

class User(ndb.Model):
    oauth_token = ndb.StringProperty(required=False, indexed=False)

    @classmethod
    def update_data(self):
        logging.info("uid = %s, oauth token = %s" % (self.key, self.oauth_token))
        api = Api.Init(self.oauth_token)
```

In a separate file `test.py`, I have the following code:

```
from models import User
from google.appengine.ext import webapp, ndb
import logging

class Test(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        uid = 1
        u = ndb.Key(User, str(uid)).get()
        logging.info("uid = %s, oauth token = %s" % (u.key.string_id(), u.oauth_token))
        u.update_data()
```

Here's the output in the log:

```
INFO     2012-07-22 16:32:42,532 test.py:8] uid = Key('User', '1'), oauth token = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
INFO     2012-07-22 16:32:42,532 user.py:9] uid = ModelKey('__key__'), oath token = StringProperty('oauth_token', indexed=False)
```

Why am I getting `StringProperty('oauth_token', indexed=False)` instead of the actual property's value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`update_data` is decorated with `@classmethod`, which means that `self` in `update_data` is a reference to the User class, instead of an instance method. Just remove `@classmethod`.

Comment: Thanks. I guess as somebody coming from C# I got the wrong idea that `@classmethod` made the method an instance method.